# Time delays when using two high-res cameras

Tags: ros, camera, images

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an application where I want to use two Basler cameras simultaneously. When I use a single camera, or set the region of interest to be low for both cameras, there is a small time delay associated with sending the image message from the camera node to a listener node (10 ms). When I use both however, there is a significant time delay in the received images (300 ms). I've created a small test node that listens on the image messages for verifying this:

```
delay_ms = (rospy.Time.now() - msg.header.stamp).to_nsec() / 1e6
```

Following previous answers, I've tried increasing the buff_size parameter in the subscribers but that doesn't help. I've also tried to [increase the TCP window size in linux](https://fasterdata.es.net/host-tuning/linux/) but that doesn't help either.

I'm wondering where the bottleneck is exactly. Is it in the TCP/IP stack itself or could it be the serialization of the large images that causes latency? How do I check for these?

**Additional Info:**

- I'm using the basler_camera package for reading images from the cameras.
- The computer has 4 cores and 8 GB of RAM

**camera 1:**

- 1280x960 RGB
- 20 MByte/s bw in rostopic

**camera 2:**

- 2048x1088 Mono
- 330 MByte/s bw in rostopic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266923/time-delays-when-using-two-high-res-cameras/) by [samlcharreyron](https://answers.ros.org/users/19673/samlcharreyron/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After looking at it further, I realized the problem is not in the TCP/IP stack but rather due to CPU utilization. I noticed that each camera node used 100% of a CPU core and with listeners attached the CPU utilization was maxed out, probably resulting in queuing on the CPU side rather than in the network. Switching to a faster machine solved the problem for me.

---

Originally posted by [samlcharreyron](https://answers.ros.org/users/19673/samlcharreyron/) with karma: 36 on 2017-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2017-07-24**:
Feel free to accept this as the answer to close out the question